# .htaccess wordpress + subdirectory static page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have installed on my server Wordperss and inside i have subdirectory with static page & in this subdirectory i have another subdirectory with another static page.

I have problem because rewrite rules for static pages not working - redirect to WP blog.

```
domain.com - wordpress
domain.com/archive/ - first static
domain.cin/archive/old/ - second static
```

In each of this directories i have .htaccess file.

Here's code of this files.

WordPress

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

domain.com/archive/.htaccess

```
Options All -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /archive/

RewriteRule ^$ index.html
```

domain.com/archive/old/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /archive/old/


RewriteRule ^$ index.php

RewriteRule ^archiwum\.html$ /index.php?p=archiwum [L]

RewriteRule ^warsztaty.html$ /index.php?p=warsztaty
RewriteRule ^kontakt.html$ /index.php?p=kontakt
RewriteRule ^warsztaty-([0-9]+).html$ /warsztaty.php?p=warsztaty-$1 

RewriteRule ^archiwum.html$ /index.php?p=archiwum

RewriteRule ^galerie.html$ /index.php?p=galeria-all
RewriteRule ^galeria-([0-9]+).html$ /galeria-$1.php 

RewriteRule ^artykul/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+).html$ /index.php?art=$1 

RewriteRule ^cache.html$ /cache.php
```

And this redirects not working - every time redirect to index of wordpress.
Only RewriteRule ^$ index.php works fine.